# JavaScript calculator using parseFloat

Tags: javascript, forms, parsefloat

I need help finishing a college assignment. I need to create a BMI calculator using the function `calcBMI ()` that will take the values from the text inputs and place the total in the 3rd input. The calculated value then needs to be converted to a floating-point number by using the `parseFloat ()` function. The text inputs then need to be references within the function using the `getElementById ()` method. Finally the calculation must be preformed by adding an event listener that listens for a click event on the button that has been included in the form and executes the `calcBMI ()` function if the event occurs.

I don't quite know how to use the `parseFloat ()` function, which I think is what is stopping me from finishing this project. And by the way, I've already asked my professor and he said that it can't use use jQuery or any other library, only pure JavaScript.

```
<form method="post" name="frmBMI">
 <div>
  <label for="bmi_weight">Weight</label>
  <input type="text" id="bmi_weight" placeholder="Weight"> lbs.
 </div>

 <div>
  <label for="bmi_height">Height</label>
  <input type="text" id="bmi_height" placeholder="Height"> in.
 </div>

 <div>
  <label for="bmi_amt">BMI</label>
  <input type="text" id="bmi_amt" placeholder="Total" readonly>
 </div>

 <div>
  <input type="submit" onclick="calcBMI ();" value="Calculate BMI">
 </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function calcBMI () {
  h = document.getElementById ("bmi_height").value;
  w = document.getElementById ("bmi_weight").value;
  document.getElementById ("bmi_amt").innerHTML = h / w;
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the value of the input field to the `parseFloat` function which if successful will return a number that you could use to make arithmetic with:

```
function calcBMI () {
    var h = parseFloat(document.getElementById("bmi_height").value);
    var w = parseFloat(document.getElementById("bmi_weight").value);
    var result = h / w;
    document.getElementById ("bmi_amt").innerHTML = result;
}
```

Of course the user could enter any arbitrary text in the input fields and you'd better check if it is a valid number using the [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function:

```
function calcBMI () {
    var h = parseFloat(document.getElementById("bmi_height").value);
    var w = parseFloat(document.getElementById("bmi_weight").value);
    if (isNaN(h) || isNaN(w)) {
        alert('Please enter a valid number');
    } else {
        var result = h / w;
        document.getElementById("bmi_amt").innerHTML = result;
    }
}
```

There's also another important aspect that you should be aware of when using the `parseFloat` function. It is culture agnostic. This means that the decimal separator is **always** `.`. So if your users local culture uses `,` as a decimal separator you might want to replace it with a `.` before passing it to the `parseFloat` function. Failing to do so, the `parseFloat` function will stop parsing at the `,` sign and you might get unexpected results.

---

UPDATE:

To avoid the form being reloaded you should make sure that you are returning `false` from the `onclick` handler of your submit button:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="calcBMI(); return false;" value="Calculate BMI" />
```

or just have your `calcBMI` function return `false`:

```
function calcBMI () {
    var h = parseFloat(document.getElementById("bmi_height").value);
    var w = parseFloat(document.getElementById("bmi_weight").value);
    if (isNaN(h) || isNaN(w)) {
        alert('Please enter a valid number');
    } else {
        var result = h / w;
        document.getElementById("bmi_amt").innerHTML = result;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and then when registering your `onclick` handler return the result from this function:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return calcBMI();" value="Calculate BMI" />
```

Basically this will prevent the default action of the form which is submitting it back to the server and displaying the calculated result.

Comment: @MathewCampbell Additionally, If you just googled "javascript parseFloat" the first result would have told you with dozens of examples. Please try google first next time.

Comment: @MicahWilliamson I did that, but I couldn't figure out how to get those examples to fit mine.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I replaced my JS with yours and it didn't do any calculations. All it did was reload the form.

Comment: @MatthewCampbell, you need to return false from the `onclick` handler of your submit button if you want this to happen. See my updated answer.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I must be missing something. Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2a8g67rp/2/. It returns a `Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.` error when I click the submit button. I used your 2nd version.

Comment: Yes, in your fiddle you are missing some stuff. Check out this one: https://jsfiddle.net/2a8g67rp/3/ To assign a value to an input element you should use `value` and not `innerHTML`: `document.getElementById("bmi_amt").value = result;`. Also you should place your `calcBMI` function at the appropriate place instead of incorrectly wrapping it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now for a random Zelda quote, "You are great. You have an amazing wisdom and power."